# Sort columns based on multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below

```
  release  count
0    2.18    602
1     3.0    617
2     1.9    168
3    2.15    590
4    2.21    622
5    2.19    606
6    2.17    595
7    2.20    617
8     2.3    617
```

I want column `count` to be given first preference in sorting then column `release`.

Expected Answer is

```
  release  count
2     1.90    168
3     2.15    590
6     2.17    595
0     2.18    602
5     2.19    606
7     2.20    617
4     2.21    622
8     2.30    617
1     3.00    617
```

Comment: Where does your own function come into play here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an idea and implemented the below

```
def sort_df_by_release(df):
    release_list = df.release.tolist()
    release_list.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x.split('.')[0]), int(x.split('.')[1])))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in release_list:
        new_df = new_df.append(df.loc[df.release == i])
    new_df = new_df.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
    return new_df
```

This is working for me now.

Answer (score 2):

We can use sort_values to sort our dataframe based on multiple keys.

`df.sort_values(by=['count','release'], inplace = True)`

The first key `count` will give the first level of sorting, while `release` will be the second level of sorting.

You don't have to create a separate function to make python sort

Comment: It is possible to use a different transform function for the `key` parameter, one function associated with one `by` entry? I'm trying with a dictionary, but can't find the correct syntax, and the documentation don't mention this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are strings and need sorting like floats.

Use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with column converted to floats for positions of sorted values, so added [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for change ordering:

```
df = df.iloc[df['release'].astype(float).argsort()]
print (df)
   release  count
2     1.90    168
3     2.15    590
6     2.17    595
0     2.18    602
5     2.19    606
7     2.20    617
4     2.21    622
8     2.30    617
1     3.00    617
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use the function [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values)

As such:

```
df.sort_values(by=['release'])
```